# missing dependencies - Grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.1

i am  getting error like this

```
| Loading Grails 2.1.4
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 2 source files.....
| Error Error: The following plugins failed to load due to missing dependencies: [cacheHeaders]
- Plugin: cacheHeaders
   - Dependencies:
       - controllers (Required: 1.1 > *, Found: 2.1.4) 
       ! logging (Required: 1.1 > *, Found: Not Installed) [INVALID]
```

I am using
Grials 2.1.4
After added plugins
 cache-1.0.1
 cache-hearders -1.5.1
    i am getting above error.

In Grails documentation it is saying these will support Grails 2.1 also.
Grails version : 1.2 > *   -- i understand this meaning is, it supports to 2.1.4 also. 
please refer: http://grails.org/plugins/search?q=cache-headers

```
else could you please refer any references to do "**cached-resourses in 2.1.4**".
```

But i did a Sample Grails(2.1.4) App and added same plugins. And it is running perfectly.

My SampleApplication:

```
APPLICATION STATUS
App version: 0.1
Grails version: 2.1.4
Groovy version: 1.8.8
JVM version: 1.7.0_15
Reloading active: true
Controllers: 1
Domains: 0
Services: 3
Tag Libraries: 13

INSTALLED PLUGINS
logging - 2.1.4
core - 2.1.4
codecs - 2.1.4
i18n - 2.1.4
urlMappings - 2.1.4
dataSource - 2.1.4
controllers - 2.1.4
servlets - 2.1.4
mavenPublisher - 0.8.1
resources - 1.1.6
webxml - 1.4.1
databaseMigration - 1.3.2
cacheHeaders - 1.1.5
jquery - 1.8.3
tomcat - 2.1.4
groovyPages - 2.1.4
domainClass - 2.1.4
filters - 2.1.4
converters - 2.1.4
mimeTypes - 2.1.4
scaffolding - 2.1.4
hibernate - 2.1.4
validation - 2.1.4
services - 2.1.4
cache - 1.0.1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that in the first application the error is about a missing logging plugin:

```
! logging (Required: 1.1 > *, Found: Not Installed) [INVALID]
```

While in the working application you are using logging 2.1.4:

```
INSTALLED PLUGINS
logging - 2.1.4
```

Comment: My application implemented in 2.0.4, I am trying to migrate to Grails 2.1.4 So, I tried with Sample grails app, it(cache-headers) is working there. But in my application not working. What i am feeling, some where forward compatibility not working.

Comment: Is the logging plugin defined in your application.properties file? this seems to be the missing dependency

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it,

```
 commented this line in BuildConfig.groovy

   //excludes   "grails-plugin-log4j"
```

it working fine, but i don't know much details about that. My boss advised it. Thanks to my Boss.